Problems with printf formating when porting PlatformIO from Windows to Mac
When running PlatformIO under Windows 11, statements like "printf("value = %d, value);" work just fine for many types of integer such as uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, etc.and even enumerated types and bool.  However, when PlatformIO is ported to a Mac, it objects, requring the format to be %lu if  value is of type uint32_t for example.  How can this be fixed without changing many hundred uses of %d in thousands lines of code. Why is printf so picky when running in a Mac?
I expected that change of OS not to impact on the PlatformIO compiler!

Please post actual code and the actual error and/or warning messages you get.  As text - not as images.

Regarding How can this be fixed without changing many hundred uses of %d in thousands lines of code.?  No one can say for sure without seeing your code.  Just because it appeared to work on Windows doesn't make it correct.  It might very well be bad code: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."  If it's wrong, it's wrong and should be fixed.

Here is example code:

I do not understand why my example got lost in my reply!
Here it is it again:
uint32_t a = 1;
uint8_t b = 2;
bool c = true;
printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
This compiles fine in PlatformIO running under Windows but not when running on a Mac.
